# Imagick .heic format not supported in php (xampp) but in console

Tags: php, xampp, imagick

I am not able to detect or convert heic images in php with Imagick. Strangely enough I can read and even convert images with the command line. Other formats like png, jpeg, pdf, etc. work just fine.

I am using "`Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-48 Q16 x64`" on XAMPP for Windows. The console tells me that heic is an buil-in Delegation. But printing out `Imagick::queryFormats()` in php doesn't show any signs of heic as supported formats.
Also when trying to read an image blob it throws an `Imagick:NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat "" @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/449` error.

Why does the console support the format but php doesn't? Am I missing some files?
I've tried to google, but - as usual - searching for imagick related stuff brings no success.

Comment: Check if there is an entry in the delegates.xml file for heic. If so, be sure it has the full path to heic. This happens with PDF files and ghostscript (gs). The delegates.xml file just shows gs, but it needs the full path to ghostscript in front of gs. So perhaps this is happening for heic files. Sorry, this is just a guess. I have not used heic files, yet.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is the following: the installation you did of Imagick in PHP doesn't have the support for .heic format. I recommend that you do the following: copy all the DLL's from the ImageMagick installation directory.

**C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.11-Q16-HDRI**

Then, paste the DLL's into the following directory:

**C:\xampp\apache\bin**.

Note: the name of the DLL's files starts with "CORE_", as shown in the following picture.
[image]